# When I reconfigure syslog, my application logs don't follow the new configuration

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I have a question about a syslog application. I wrote a simple program using syslog API.
I compiled and launched the program. It works, I can see logs on the journal.

However, when I reconfigured syslog to send logs to a remote server, the program kept sending logs locally. The remote syslog server is working, I check with
`logger -p daemon.info test: testing log` and I can see the message `testing log` on the remote side.

Once I restarted the program, it worked, and logs were sent to a remote server.

Thus, it seems a syslog application needs to restart when the syslog daemon is restarted?

The code

```
#include <syslog.h>        
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    setlogmask (LOG_UPTO (LOG_NOTICE));
    int i = 0;

    openlog ("exampleprog", LOG_CONS | LOG_PID | LOG_NDELAY, LOG_LOCAL1);
    while (1){
            syslog (LOG_NOTICE, "Program started by User %d, msg numer %d", getuid (),++i);
            sleep(2);
    }

    closelog ();
    return 0;
    }
```

compile and run

```
 gcc test.c && ./a.out
```

To reproduce

- No remote syslog server is configured
- compiled and start the program
- configure a remote syslog server => No logs are sent by the program to the remote server.
- restart the program => logs are present in the remote server.

Distrib and rsyslog version on the local and remote are ubuntu-20.04 and rsyslogd 8.2001.0

Answer (score 0):

Finally, chatGPT gives an answer to me.

> *To avoid having to restart the program after each change to the syslog configuration, you can consider using the `syslog()` function with the `LOG_ODELAY` option instead of the `LOG_NDELAY` option. The `LOG_ODELAY` option causes the syslog API to re-read the configuration file each time a log message is sent, ensuring that changes to the syslog configuration are reflected immediately in your program.*

whereas the answer is not explicit on `syslog` man page:

> `LOG_ODELAY`
>
> The converse of `LOG_NDELAY`; opening of the connection is delayed until `syslog()` is called. (This is the default, and need not be specified.)

So change:

```
openlog ("exampleprog", LOG_CONS | LOG_PID | LOG_NDELAY, LOG_LOCAL1);
```

to

```
openlog ("exampleprog", LOG_CONS | LOG_PID, LOG_LOCAL1);
```